# Getting elements of an array depending on corresponding values of another - Lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have two JavaScript arrays:

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = [ 1,  0,  0,  1 ];
```

I want another array getting elements from array1 where the corresponding  elements of array 2 in the same position  match a condition. Both arrays must have the same elements.

For example:
I want elements of array1 where the corresponding elements of array2 are 0

```
Result = ['b','c']
```

Another example:
I want elements of array1 where corresponding elements of array2 are 1

```
Result = ['a','d']
```

I'm looking for a function on Lodash or Underscore Js Libraries to do this. I can implement it using vanilla javascript, but I'm curious to know if this can be done with these Libraries.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the same as in plain Javascript.

```
filtered0 = array1.filter((_, i) => array2[i] === 0);
filtered1 = array1.filter((_, i) => array2[i] === 1);
```

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'],
    array2 = [ 1,  0,  0,  1 ];

console.log(_.filter(array1, (a, i) => array2[i] === 0));
console.log(_.filter(array1, (a, i) => array2[i] === 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works!, Thanks a lot. For non EC6 connoisseurs, this is the code:

Comment: console.log(_.filter(array1, function(a, i) { return array2[i] === 0 }));

Answer (score 2):

This can be done elegantly by adding the following method to lodash:

```
_.mixin({'iter': xs => (w => () => w.next().value)(_(xs))})
```

Basically, it returns a function that iterates an array, that is, each invocation returns the next array element. With `iter`, your problem is easy:

```js
var array1 = ['a','b','c','d'];
var array2 = [ 1,  0,  0,  1 ];

_.mixin({'iter': xs => (w => () => w.next().value)(_(xs))});

// positives

pos = _.filter(array1, _.iter(array2))
console.log(pos)

// negatives

neg = _.reject(array1, _.iter(array2))
console.log(neg)

// both

group = _.groupBy(array1, _.iter(array2))
console.log(group)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Cool. It's most that I needed, but great input! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can [zip()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#zip), [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#filter), and [map()](https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#map), like this:

```
_.chain()
  .zip(array1, array2)
  .filter(_.property(1))
  .map(0)
  .value();
```

You can get the zero values by negating the filter predicate, like this:

```
_.chain()
  .zip(array1, array2)
  .filter(_.negate(_.property(1)))
  .map(0)
  .value();
```

Comment: Or simpler: `_(array1).zip(array2).reject(1).map(0).value()`

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom function and use `filter()` but both arrays must be of same length.

```js
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
var array2 = [1, 0, 0, 1];

function filterBy(el) {
  return array1.filter(function(e, i) {
    return array2[i] == el;
  })
}

console.log(filterBy(0))
console.log(filterBy(1))
```